# Realm migration with big data base

Tags: database, migration, realm

I need to implement a migration with processing a large amount of data (more than 2,000,000 records). When I check the migration the memory grows linearly to 2.4 GB (iPad Pro 12.9 1 gen) and the application crashes. How can I split the migration into several steps so that it doesn't consume so much memory? I tried to convert blob data to several realm models.

Before:

```
@interface RealmDataModel : RLMObject

@property NSData *data; // The data stored in JSON format with different types

@end
```

After:

```
@interface RealmDataModel : RLMObject

@property RLMArray<RealmNew1Model *>< RealmNew1Model > *type1;
@property RLMArray<RealmNew2Model *>< RealmNew2Model > *type2;
@property RLMArray<RealmNew3Model *>< RealmNew3Model > *type3;

@end
```

Migration:

```
[migration enumerateObjects:@"RealmDataModel" block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {  
    NSArray *dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:oldObject.data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:error];
    for (NSDictionary *someObject in dataArray) {
        if (someObject[@"type"] == @(1)) {
            RLMObject *new1Object = [migration createObject:@"RealmNew1Model" withValue:@{}];
            // convert someObject to the RealmNew1Model
        } else if (someObject[@"type"] == @(2)) {
            RLMObject *new2Object = [migration createObject:@"RealmNew2Model" withValue:@{}];
            // convert someObject to the RealmNew2Model
        } else if (someObject[@"type"] == @(3)) {
            RLMObject *new3Object = [migration createObject:@"RealmNew3Model" withValue:@{}];
            // convert someObject to the RealmNew3Model
        }
    }
}];
```